# Animations not working in swift playgrounds after button pressed

Tags: swift, sprite

I have a mouse down function that calls a function of another class in which the instance is named `formation`

```
override public func mouseDown(with event: NSEvent) {


    let location = event.location(in: self)
    let touchedNode = self.atPoint(location)

    print(location)

    else if touchedNode.name == "navRight"
    {

        formation.pageOne()
    }
}
```

and with that line i call the `pageOne()` function

```
func pageOne()
{
    print("in page one")
    earthNode.runAction(cpalAccessor.arcRoll())
    spaceNode.runAction(cpalAccessor.arcRoll())
}
```

and the output is simply `in page one` and the animations do not carry out. Can someone help me with this?

Comment: and even if i try to print out something such as "done" after the two animations, the console doesn't even get to that line so the output is still simply "in page one"